# how do i change the size of a picture using the mouse on pyqt4

Tags: image, resize, qt4, pyqt4, pixmap

how do i change the size of a picture using the mouse button like we do in Microsoft Word or Adobe Photoshop ?

this is my code

```
class Ui_Form(object):
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
    Form.resize(923, 655)
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 771, 501))
    self.label.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("moon.png")))
    self.label.setScaledContents(True)
    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
```

Example :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqkB9.png)

Comment: is there any other way to resize a picture like clicking on it and changing its size ?